# Django and Ajax: SyntaxError: Unexpected token D in JSON at position 0 at parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: json, django, ajax, syntax-error

The backend to my project is django (I am working on the 4th page of my project).  I have a series of forms and inputs that take input data and then roll the inputs into a json object.  I have checked to make sure that the json object is valid (pulled it from the console and used a json validator) after using stringify (var modelData_toserver = JSON.stringify(modelData).  The resultant json is:

```
{"data":[{"depth":[0]},{"temp":[1]},{"lakename":"m"},{"lakeId":"m"},{"area":"1"},{"fetch":"1"},{"maxDepth":"1"},{"lat":"1"},{"long":"1"},{"airTemp":"1"},{"shelterFactor":"1"},{"extinctCoeff":"1"},{"dispersion":"1"},{"longWave":"1"}]}
```

My ajax code is (modelData_toserver is the json):

```
function sendInputs(modelData_toserver, name){

    var urlViews = "/beach/bmominputs/" + name + "/"
    console.log(urlViews)

    $.ajax({
            url: urlViews,
            type:"POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: modelData_toserver,

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Lake Characteristics Data Not Delivered Properly');

                $('#result').html('<p>status code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
                console.log('jqXHR:');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('textStatus:');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log('errorThrown:');
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log('datatype:');
                console.log(typeof data);
            },

            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('Data Sent Sucessfully');
            }
    });
```

I am pretty sure my url.py is pointing properly to my view since if I input my URL directly into the browser it prints out the HttpResponse of the view -- HttpResponse("Data Posted Successfully").  I suspect that the stingify javascript is causing problems but not sure how to convert variable values to strings another way.

Thank you for any help you can provide in figuring out this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token D in JSON at position 0 at parse ().

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (changes as follows):

```
changed the data format that I send (got rid of quotes and the data key, cleaned it up to be ..)
var modelData = {depth: depthArray, temp: temperatureArray, lakename: lakeName.val(),lakeId: lakeId.val(), area: area.val(),fetch: fetch.val(), maxDepth: maxDepth.val(),lat: lat.val(),long: long.val(),airTemp: airTemp.val(),shelterFactor: shelterFactor.val(),extinctCoeff: extinctCoeff.val(),dispersion: dispersion.val(),longWave: longWave.val()};
``
Second, modified the content type to:
```

contentType: 'application/json',

```
Added a whole bunch of cross-scripting stuff that I barely understand from here:

https://andrewstestingfiles.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/csrf.html

To get the entire json, I used the following in the view
```

modeldict = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))